# Java - What is the "industry standard" method to communicate between client and server in terms of using strings, etc

Tags: java, sockets, networking

So usually, to have get and set methods in networking Java I use an enum, for example:

public enum MyEnum {
    GET_NAME,
    GET_ADDRESS;
}

etc. which the client application and server application would send between each other as a string and the appropriate task would be carried out.

I wanted to know how applications do this usually? What data do they send through the socket to make the program work, do they use ObjectStreams? Do they send bytes?

Wanted to know what the best practice would be to have a client-server setup for my own messaging application.

EXTRA INFO:
The client / server network I'm designing is for a PLUGIN in a GAME and therefore has to be instant / speedy ;)

Comment: Consider https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thank you but that does not look suitable as it isn't a class instance that I am trying to serialize efficiently, it is mainly getting and setting primitives from a minecraft server to a serversocket.

Comment: At some point, you're going to have to send coherent messages in the form of bytes from a client to a server and vice versa.  You can't e.g. make objects automagically correspond between two different locations.  Is there a reason those messages couldn't take the form of objects?

Comment: I could, but then the parsing etc. would your idea not be slower than printing three strings through a local host data stream?

Comment: Sure, potentially.  Why use strings instead of e.g. an enum, which can be represented in single digits of bits?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'll change my design and go with protocol-buffers.

Comment: I appreciate the accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of that. Or something else.

The "industry" standard can be many things, depending on the domain you are looking at, or the decade when the solution was designed.

In 2018, most "new" client/server communication that gets defined doesn't operate on socket level. You rather define a set of restful APIs that the server offers, and data flows as JSON strings for example.

In other words: the official answer here is: there is no such as an industry-wide standard. To the contrary: what you are asking about (sending individual comments on socket level) is probably the *exception*, and not something that is common for real world architectures. People don't think in sockets and single commands. They think in terms of protocols, abstractions, maybe "remote procedure calls".

Comment: Sure. And dont forget to cleanup no longer required comments ;-)